# Looping over elements to change font in math mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode, loops

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\ident}[1]{\texttt{\small #1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ci[1]{%
    \def\citmp{}%
    \@for\reserved:=#1\do{%
        \protected@edef\citmp{\citmp\ifx\citmp\empty\else,\fi\ident{\reserved}}%
    }%
    \{\citmp\}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\ci{a,b,c}$ % (1)

$\ci{a, b, c}$ % (2)

$\{\ident{a}, \ident{b}, \ident{c} \}$ % (3)

\end{document}
```

(The code for `\ci` is taken from an answer on this site; I can't find the URL right now, though.)

This contains two problems:

1. <strike>Lines `(1)` and `(2)` report those warnings, whereas line `(3)`, which should (from what I understand, at least), be identical to line `(1)`, does not:</strike> (Solved by jfbu, thanks!)

   ```
   LaTeX Font Warning: Command \relax \GenericWarning {(Font)              }{LaTeX
    Font Warning: Command \relax \GenericWarning {(Font)              }{LaTeX Font
    Warning: Command \relax \fontsize {9}{11}\selectfont \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ 
   plus3\p@ minus4\p@ \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ plus2\p@ \belowdisplayshortskip 4
   \p@ plus2\p@ minus2\p@ \def \leftmargin \leftmargini \parsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minu
   s\p@ \topsep 8\p@ plus2\p@ minus4\p@ \itemsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@ {\leftmarg
   in \leftmargini \topsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus2\p@ \parsep 2\p@ plus\p@ minus\p@         itemsep \parsep }\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip invalid in math mode}\font
   size {9}{11}\selectfont \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ plus3\p@ minus4\p@ \abovedispl
   ayshortskip \z@ plus2\p@ \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus2\p@ \def \l
   eftmargin \leftmargini \parsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@ \topsep 8\p@ plus2\p@ min
   us4\p@ \itemsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@ {\leftmargin \leftmargini \topsep 4\p@ p
   lus2\p@ minus2\p@ \parsep 2\p@ plus\p@ minus\p@ \itemsep \parsep }\belowdisplay
   skip \abovedisplayskip invalid in math mode}\fontsize {9}{11}\selectfont \above
   displayskip 8.5\p@ plus3\p@ minus4\p@ \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ plus2\p@ \belo
   wdisplayshortskip 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus2\p@ \def \leftmargin \leftmargini \parsep
    4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@ \topsep 8\p@ plus2\p@ minus4\p@ \itemsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ 
   minus\p@ {\leftmargin \leftmargini \topsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus2\p@ \parsep 2\p@
    plus\p@ minus\p@ \itemsep \parsep }\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip invalid
    in math mode on input line 17.

   LaTeX Font Warning: Command \relax \GenericWarning {(Font)              }{LaTeX
    Font Warning: Command \relax \fontsize {9}{11}\selectfont \abovedisplayskip 8.
   5\p@ plus3\p@ minus4\p@ \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ plus2\p@ \belowdisplayshorts
   kip 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus2\p@ \def \leftmargin \leftmargini \parsep 4\p@ plus2\p@
    minus\p@ \topsep 8\p@ plus2\p@ minus4\p@ \itemsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@ {\lef
   tmargin \leftmargini \topsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus2\p@ \parsep 2\p@ plus\p@ minus
   \p@ \itemsep \parsep }\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip invalid in math mode}
   \fontsize {9}{11}\selectfont \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ plus3\p@ minus4\p@ \above
   displayshortskip \z@ plus2\p@ \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus2\p@ \d
   ef \leftmargin \leftmargini \parsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@ \topsep 8\p@ plus2\p
   @ minus4\p@ \itemsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@ {\leftmargin \leftmargini \topsep 4
   \p@ plus2\p@ minus2\p@ \parsep 2\p@ plus\p@ minus\p@ \itemsep \parsep }\belowdi
   splayskip \abovedisplayskip invalid in math mode on input line 17.

   LaTeX Font Warning: Command \relax \fontsize {9}{11}\selectfont \abovedisplaysk
   ip 8.5\p@ plus3\p@ minus4\p@ \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ plus2\p@ \belowdisplays
   hortskip 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus2\p@ \def \leftmargin \leftmargini \parsep 4\p@ plu
   s2\p@ minus\p@ \topsep 8\p@ plus2\p@ minus4\p@ \itemsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@ 
   {\leftmargin \leftmargini \topsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus2\p@ \parsep 2\p@ plus\p@ 
   minus\p@ \itemsep \parsep }\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip invalid in math 
   mode on input line 17.
   ```

   The same warnings are repeated for the other line.
2. Line `(2)` is formatted differently (see below) than lines `(1)` and `(3)`, since the spaces between the commas and the elements are copied to the output instead of ignored. This is not that bad since I can always use the version in line `(1)`, but I wonder if there is a way to simply ignore the spaces.

   [image]

Comment: To address your 1.: use `\DeclareRobustCommand*` rather than `\newcommand*` for the definition of the `\ident` macro.

Comment: And to address your 2., you can try with replacing `\small #1` with `\small\ignorespaces #1` in `\ident`.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the second problem too! Just FYI, I put the `\ignorespaces` into the definition of `\ci` since I'm using `\ident` in other places too. If you add your comments as an answer I'll accept them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue `1.` originates in the fact that your `\ident` macro is not protected against expansion (and `\small` from inside `\ident` is executed at a time when `\texttt` has not effectively made an exit from math mode, hence the first of the error). Using

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\ident}etc...
```

rather than

```
\newcommand*{\ident}
```

will instruct `\protected@edef` to not expand (too much) `\ident`.

The second issue `2.` can be handled by the use of `\ignorespaces` prior to where an unwanted space could occur, here a space right after a comma which ends up inside `\reserved`: so `\ignorespaces #1` in the definition of `\ident` or rather as you mentioned in a comment `\ignorespaces\reserved` in `\ci`.